# Add/Remove css class using jQuery to identify elements by a css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a javascript / jQuery function below:

```
    function hideShowHiddens(action){
        $('.hidden_col').each(function(){
            if(action == 'show'){
                this.removeClass("hidden");
            }else{
                this.addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    }
```

What it should do is search a jsp for every element with the empty marker css '.hidden_col'. Then based on the parmenter entered, it will either add or remove another css class called '.hidden' which actually hides the elements.

This method will ideally save me 400 lines of javascript functions that is too slow for the amount of data I need to work with. However, when it runs I get an error from the browser saying that it doesn't support this method. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` are jQuery functions. jQuery objects are supersets of standard DOM objects. You need to wrap the DOM object to create a jQuery object. Then the functions become accessible.

```
function hideShowHiddens(action){
    $('.hidden_col').each(function(){
        if(action == 'show'){
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
}
```

**Example:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Hyb/)

**Alternative:**

Here is a shorter, sweeter alternative.

```
function hideShowHiddens(action){
    (action === "show") ? $('.hidden_col').show() : $('.hidden_col').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked and it was much faster than my other code thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing `$ selector`, try this `$(this).removeClass("hidden")` and `$(this).addClass("hidden");`

Answer (score 0):

The concreted problem is that `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. You can simplify your code to and just omit the `.each` loop:

```
function hideShowHiddens(action){
    $('.hidden_col').toggleClass('hidden', action !== 'show');
}
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch